# How to replace a value in a query if it meets some condition?

Tags: ms-access

For example I have a query Q that returns Customer IDs with Offices.
However, I have a separate query S that contains a list of Customer ID's that should be hard-coded to, say, Atlanta under certain contexts.

So how would I say "run Query Q, but if the Customer ID is present in S, then instead of using the normal Office value, use the Office value from S"

Example Q: query: select CustID, Office from SourceTable

Example S: Table: A list of CustID's

So for example if I displayed Q by itself let's say I had:

```
JONES1     Las Vegas
SMITH2     Miami
```

But JONES1 is in S, so I want it to actually display

```
JONES1     Atlanta
SMITH2     Miami
```

(all custID's in S should display Atlanta when I pull up Q)

Comment: Using the query design window, add both tables and add a join by dragging the related field from one table to the other, right click the line you have just drewn and make sure you are selecting all records from Q and only related records from S. Select the field you want. Switch to SQL view and post the sql back here with a note on where it does not suit your requirement, if any.

Comment: You can use an outer join on Query S with the Nz() funciton in the main query. If you edit your question to show query Q and query S I can explain better.

Comment: Updated the OP with some sample SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something on these lines:

```
 SELECT q.CustID, IIf(IsNull(s.Office), q.Office, s.Office) 
 FROM SourceTable q
 LEFT JOIN s
 ON q.CustID = s.CustID
```

Comment: My Q query is actually extremely more complex than the one I've shown; is there a way to do this from the Design View window?

Comment: Perhaps you did not get a chance to read my comment to your post, which describes how to use the query design window for this?

Comment: I just saw it again which is why I've gone ahead and accepted this as answer. Thanks!